# Trouble with jQuery when on an array of promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function bar() {

  var promiseArray = [];

  $.each(options, function (index, option) {
    promiseArray.push(
      someAjaxFunction(option)
    );
  });

  return $.when.apply($, promiseArray);
}
```

I have this function `bar()`

Which is called in a situation like:

```
foo().then(bar()).then(function (data) { console.log(arguments); console.log(data); });
```

Which logs out

```
["OK↵sdfadsfasd/sdfadsfads"]
```

(where the random letters are string related to the context but not remotely what it should return)

If inside `bar` instead of returning the promise, I do:

```
return $.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function(){ console.log(arguments) });
```

That works as expected and returns an array of objects that are the contents of the ajax request bodies

I'm guessing it is something to do with the $.when.apply being on an unspecified number of ajax calls

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "..something to do with the $.when.apply being on an unspecified number of ajax calls" - nope, not the problem. This is exactly what apply is for: to pass an array (of "any" length) as variadic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `bar` function as a reference.

```
foo().then(bar())
```

should be

```
foo().then(bar)
```

`.then(bar())` would mean that you are passing a deferred to `then` as an argument. You need to pass a function to `then` as an argument. The function you pass may return a deferred.

---

If you'd like `bar` to still execute immediately as `.then(bar())`, you'll need to rewrite `bar` such that it returns a function that returns a deferred:

```
function bar() {

  var promiseArray = [];

  $.each(options, function (index, option) {
    promiseArray.push(
      someAjaxFunction(option)
    );
  });

  //this function gets passed to `.then` and its return value is used
  //for the purpose of chaining deferreds
  return function () {
    return $.when.apply($, promiseArray);
  };
}
```